# Why HSQLDB doesn't lock row when use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE with MVCC concurrency control model

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, hsqldb, pessimistic-locking

I am trying to synchronize threads in my SpringBoot application through pessimistic locks in the database. For the test environment, I use HSQLDB. But for some reason, when calling the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` query, my all threads receive the result at the same time and continue to execute further in parallel. Although I expect threads will lock row sequentially.  I use JPA and my code to get a pessimistic lock is very simple:

```
private EntityManager entityManager;
...

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void doSomething() {
    sync();
    ...
}

public void sync() {
    MyEntity entity = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, entityId, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    log.debug("entity {} was locked", entity.getKey());
}
```

I use HSQLDB 2.6.1 and MVCC as concurrency control model. Does HSQLDB support pessimistic row locks?

Comment: Here is a possible answer to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977551/pessimistic-row-locking-with-hsqldb

Comment: @Lennier, thank you! Thus, expression `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` has no meaning when MVCC is enabled? HSQLDB doesn't allow to lock individual rows, only the entire table?

Comment: Correct, the entire table is locked in the LOCKS transaction model.